# what's the best way to convert an array to an object with some special keys like x & y with typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I just want to write a simple function which converts an array with 2 values `[7, 9]`  to an object with x & y keys like : `{ x: 7, y: 9 }`

```
interface coordinates {
  x: number;
  y: number;
}

function getAnObjectOfnum(arr: number[]): coordinates;
function getAnObjectOfnum(arg1: unknown, arg2?: unknown): coordinates {
  let coord: coordinates = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
  };
  if (Array.isArray(arg1)) {
    const converted = arg1.reduce((a, v, i) => ({ ...a, [i]: v }), {});
  }
  return coord;
}

console.log(getAnObjectOfnum([7, 9]));
```

That's my effort to find the solution.

Comment: Why the function overload? Why `reduce`? Neither seems to apply to what you've said you want to do.

Comment: it's just a little part of a projects the main one have got 15 overloads . the main goal is I want to manage the data entered with typescript , data's like string "x:98,y:15" , an object { f: 25, t: 48 } , etc . as I said that short part of code was my effort to find the right way because that I asked it to find the best one , you can ignore my code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to write a simple function which converts an array with 2 values `[7, 9]` to an object with x & y keys like : `{ x: 7, y: 9 }`

Unless there are requirements you're not describing in the question, it can be much simpler than that:

```typescript
function getAnObjectOfnum(arr: [number, number]): coordinates {
    return {x: arr[0], y: arr[1]};
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgQezVAJqOkDOyA3gFDLnIAeAXMiAK4C2ARtANxkUCetDL7JAL4kSMeiARhgaEMgDmEMAEEQAeWYArCJNUw+ACjhQotANp9WUADR0mlgLoBKWukw4QeCIVIVkURfRQskQ0yEZQpgAM9jY8YcamAIz2ghzCJOgg+GgANhAAdDlocvoKymqa2mC6BqYA7DYAnE6ObEA)

Note that I've used `[number, number]` rather than `number[]`, since we need **exactly** two values. This is a *tuple type*.

That can be made more concise using parameter destructuring, but possibly at the expense of clarity (or possibly not; if you're familiar with destructuring, it's clearer than I would have thought):

```typescript
function getAnObjectOfnum([x, y]: [number, number]): coordinates {
    return {x, y};
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgQezVAJqOkDOyA3gFDLnIAeAXMiAK4C2ARtANxkUCetDL7JAL4kSMeiARhgaEMgDmEMAEEQAeWYArCJNUw+ACgDalADTIuAXVqG+rKGdvQLASlrpMOEHgiFSFZFCK9FCyRKbmghzCJOgg+GgANhAAdAlocvoKymqa2mC6BoYA7GYAnC7ObEA)